# Pound sign in UILabel mysteriously encoded as HTML entity

Tags: iphone, uilabel, html-entities

In my iPhone app, the application receives its data from a server in XML format and displays it in UILabel.  The data coming from the server may contain `£` sign.  This sign is not encoded in any way - just passed as is in the XML string.  The app takes this string and displays it in a UILabel.

This works just fine most of the times.  It always works fine in a simulator, including iOS 5.1, however one of the users reported a bug indicating that instead of display the `£`, the UILabel actually shows `&pound;` - which is most bizzare.

The UILabel text is set with this simple line of code:

```
contentLabel.text = [node getValueForKey:keyName];
```

I have stepped through the code with debugger and can see that the correct string value is being passed and set.  I can also see correct results on the simulator.

However (as can be seen from the image below) something going amiss on this user's phone.  Is there something I am missing?  What could be the problem here?  And, more importantly, how can I solve this?  The things are complicated by the fact that everything works fine on my phone and simulator and this user is across the country from me, so I can't get physical access to their phone.

Here's the screenshot from the simulator:

[image: Screenshot from the simulator]

And here's the screenshot from the affected user's phone:

[image: Screenshot from users's phone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have solved itself on its own.  I couldn't reproduce it on either iOS 4 or iOS 5, nor could several other users I spoke with.  Upon checking with the user who initially reported the problem, she said that after upgrading iOS from 5.1 to 5.1.1, the problem went away.  Oh well... :)

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using to parse the XML?

Try sending the user a new build over email with copious NSLogging enabled (maybe even use testflight, its brilliant - lets you see all your logs over the air as they come in) to see where the problem crops up.

Are they on a different iOS version to the simulator you were testing with? Does the problem occur all the time with their iPhone. What about your own iOS device, does it never occur?

Sorry for all the random advice, I'm just chucking stuff out there in the case that one of them fixes it.

If they're running the same app version, same device (real iPhone not simulator) and same iOS version as you I have no idea what the problem is or could be.

If you're feeling lazy (and I reccomend NOT doing this, its quite *hacky*) you could always use:

```
finalString = [firstString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"&pound;" withString:@"£"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My own device is the same iOS version but different actual phone model.  I can't afford right now to go and get a new phone, so, unfortunately, it's out of the question.  I do have enough logging to see the string that's being sent - and it doesn't have `&pound;` in it, but just the `£` sign.  Oh, and I can't get the user to install another build even if I wanted to, as we're talking about an 18-year-old intern working in a museum for whom the difference between iPhone and old Nokia phone is that the iPhone is cooler.

Comment: Darn, that's a shame. Ah well, I guess you could always go for the find/replace technique?

Comment: For now I just wish I could replicate the problem.